# Paypal checkout.js. In which cases to choose Client side, Server side or Hybrid integration?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Paypal Express Checkout (checkout.js) offers 3 integration options:

Client Side and Server Side - listed on their website.

Hybrid - for some reason not listed on the website, but listed on GitHub page.

I wonder how to understand what integration is right for specific case?
What are the pros and cons of each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look to this [brief intro](http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/). There is also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882148/client-side-vs-server-side-scripts-to-process-order) about the same topic.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is specifically about paypal, not server vs client side in general.